# Why is the program referencing the first file in the same directory, when I type "java char *"?

Tags: java, command-line, directory, output, args

```
public class Char
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String plainText = args[0];

        char [] a = plainText.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: When I run the program "java char *", it outputs "BooleanLoop.java" which is the first file in the same directory, I tested by deleting "BooleanLoop.java" file, then it output "BooleanLoop.class", the next file in the directory. The program runs smoothly if I type other characters e.g. "java char +"

Answer (score 3):

This is really a Unix CLI question.

The problem is that the wildcard (*) character gets expanded (globbed) to all the entries in the directory **prior to** being fed to java, i.e., it's translated to something like

```
java char BooleanLoop.java BooleanLoop.class etcetera etcetera
```

If you want to feed the * character to java, either wrap it in single quotes ' or escape it with a backslash .

```
java char '*'
java char \*
```

Comment: The "\*" returns \$AVG, and the '*' does as expected but my eventual goal is to have a program that works as a calculator. So I also will want the input to look something like this "3 * 3" or "3 + 3" using StdIn or something. So basically whats the easiest way to input +-*/ characters? Also thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Wrapping the whole string into single quotes will do.
Notice that using StdIn and command line args are two different things

Comment: This is my first time submitting code. Whats the best way to show you more code?